# Activate previous process on Mac

Tags: c++, macos

Is it possible to determine the previous active process to activate it?

Mac OS X / C++ / Carbon.

---

`GetNextProcess()` does not refer to Z-order of processes, but I need the real previous.

The original task is to bring the user back to their work when they closes my info window. Currently another window of my app gets the focus, if any, or there just no window with focus. It is unusable.

---

**Update.** Now I'm using the following workaround: 500ms timer watches for `GetFrontProcess()` which is not equal `GetCurrentProcess()`. Then calling `SetForegroundProcess()` for the last stored serial number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the zorder of processes from [this](http://gist.github.com/163918) place. Last process should be the one you are looking for. Or change code to read in reverse.